# Go 1.19 Error executing template: {{range}} branches end in different contexts: extra javascript line stops the error

Tags: javascript, go, templates, range

Please find example in [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/RELjQ71DT0O).  Comment (`//`) the line `onRuleAreaChange(document.getElementById('ruleArea0'));` to see the problem

I have some JavaScript that changes drop-down (SELECT) lists on forms based upon other drop-down list selections. To initialise the drop-down lists I call the `onChange` function I have written.  On initialisation of the form, I call the `onChange` function for each row of my form.

The following lines of code range over each row and makes the call for that row thus setting up the configuration of the other fields in the whole row.

```
        // Initialise all the rows
    {{- range $i,$v  := .}}
    onRuleAreaChange(document.getElementById('ruleArea{{$i}}'));
    {{- end}}
```

Go tells me that I have a `{{range}} ending in different contexts`, I'm not sure why - I looked all over the place for some missing terminator.

The fix for this was to simply add a line that is identical to the first line generated in the range loop.  i.e. initialise the first row (which I always have) before ranging over the whole set as follow:

```
       // Initialise all the rows
    onRuleAreaChange(document.getElementById('ruleArea0'));
    {{- range $i,$v  := .}}
    onRuleAreaChange(document.getElementById('ruleArea{{$i}}'));
    {{- end}}
```

Can someone see why adding this extra line resolves the problem?

The final output that works is:

```
    onRuleAreaChange(document.getElementById('ruleArea0'));
    onRuleAreaChange(document.getElementById('ruleArea0'));
    onRuleAreaChange(document.getElementById('ruleArea1'));
```

The output I would like to get but can't because of the error is:

```
    onRuleAreaChange(document.getElementById('ruleArea0'));
    onRuleAreaChange(document.getElementById('ruleArea1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/html/template#ErrorCode):

> ErrBranchEnd: "{{if}} branches end in different contexts"
> Example:
>  `{{if .C}}<a href="{{end}}{{.X}}` 
> **Discussion:**
> Package html/template statically examines each path through an {{if}}, {{range}}, or {{with}} to escape any following pipelines.
> The example is ambiguous since {{.X}} might be an HTML text node, or a URL prefix in an HTML attribute. The context of {{.X}} is used to figure out how to escape it, but that context depends on the run-time value of {{.C}} which is not statically known.
>
> The problem is usually something like missing quotes or angle brackets, or can be avoided by refactoring to put the two contexts into different branches of an if, range or with. If the problem is in a {{range}} over a collection that should never be empty, adding a dummy {{else}} can help.

When you run your example the full error is :

`html/template:test:30:18: {{range}} branches end in different contexts: {stateJS delimNone urlPartNone jsCtxRegexp attrNone elementScript <nil>}, {stateJSLineCmt delimNone urlPartNone jsCtxRegexp attrNone elementScript <nil>}`

So the differing contexts mentioned above are `stateJS` and `stateJSLineCmt`; the error is because if the `range` outputs something then the context is "javascript" otherwise it`s "Javascript Line Comment" (i.e. a continuation of the comment above). Not sure if that really explains it well but, fortunately, it's easily solved:

```
// Now initialise all the rows
/* onRuleAreaChange(document.getElementById('ruleArea0')); */
{{- range $i,$v  := .}}
onRuleAreaChange(document.getElementById('ruleArea{{$i}}'));
{{- end}}
```

Will work as expected [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/EVuDE7JPvpf) as will the following [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/AyAOTf9ztQW):

```
// Now initialise all the rows
// onRuleAreaChange(document.getElementById('ruleArea0')); 
{{- range $i,$v  := .}}
onRuleAreaChange(document.getElementById('ruleArea{{$i}}'));
{{else}}
;
{{- end}}
```

Comment: You are right the first line of the range execution is just an extension of the comment.  The solution is to remove the {{- from the range to {{range.  To be honest, the error is a bit misleading.  I would have preferred for the comment to be extended and then to see that in the HTML output.  I do have code that automatically generates comments.  So don't see how Go can assume that generated comments are not legitimate

Comment: "The solution is to" well that's one solution (I showed a couple of others on the assumption that there was a reason you wanted to trim spaces). The algorithm needs to know the context so it can apply appropriate escaping rules; it's not a perfect solution but OK for the vast majority of cases. Note that there is no assumption that "generated comments are not legitimate"; the issue is that differing branches of a statement result in differing output contexts; if this was allowed then handling escaping would be become more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Go is making the assumption that the generated code is not part of the comment.  I'm not completely convinced that it should do this because I do have generated comments in GO templates.

By removing the `-` from the `{{- range` the error doesn't happen